# Setting the DNS record to bypass Cloudflare seems to not have any immediate effect?

Tags: cloudflare

I have set up a domain name to use Cloudflare. I have tested SSL and all seems well. However I have found that it can cause webfonts to not display in IE11. So I tried to "bypass" cloudflare by clicking on the orange cloud for the status of the A and CName record withing Cloudflare\DNS. The orange cloud icon goes grey.

So I have switched from:

```
Orange Cloud: Records that display an orange cloud icon are accelerated and protected by CloudFlare
```

To:

```
Grey Cloud: Records that display a grey cloud icon will bypass CloudFlare, using only CloudFlare DNS
```

However when I then try to load up www.mydomain.com again in IE I still get "https://", as prefix, which implies that the domain is still not bypassing Cloudflare. I tried again after 10 mins, cleared temporary files and I still get no resolution.

I have now worked out that restarting the IE browser solves this, but I am not sure why. Is this to do with the 301 page redirect that my page rule invokes to "Always use https" for pattern "/*". Is there a way to clear this without closing and restarting the browser?

Linked to the above I found that I could only get "Full" SSL to work to force "HTTPS". "Flexible" SSL still allowed "HTTP" for some reason.

Advice on the above appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DNS records do have a Time To Live before the they update (I believe this is 299 seconds on domains set-up using CloudFlare full-host DNS), however I do not think this issue is a CloudFlare problem.

A https prefix does not mean a site is using CloudFlare as there could be an SSL on the origin server. Using the command line I would advise you ping the domain to find if it's routing through CloudFlare or not. You can do this by typing:

```
ping yourdomain.com
```

If it routes to your IP Address you know it's not on CloudFlare, if it points to [an IP on the CloudFlare network](https://www.cloudflare.com/ips) then you are routing through CloudFlare (in which case wait for it to propagate, clear your cache, if you still have no luck raise a support ticket with CloudFlare).